# Calculate profit in investment by a person joined x months later

Tags: percentages, ratio

A and B enter into Partnership investing rs 12000 and 6000 respectively. After 8 months, C Also joins with capital of 15000. The share of c in the profit of 45600 after 2 years will be ?

I assume the avg profit over 2 years per month is 1900. So we have to distribute 30400 for 16 months among the A, B and C.

what am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C has invested $15000$  for $(24-6)=18$ months, right?

Whereas $A,B$ have invested for $24$ months.

So, the profit ratio should be $A:B:C=12000\cdot24:6000\cdot24:15000\cdot18$